# Memory Leak when Marshal.Copy

Tags: c#, memory, memory-leaks

I noticed my program was leaking memory. So I used dotMemory to find the leak, and looks like this is the function causing the leak:

```
    private void LoadBits()
    {
        // Lock the bitmap's bits.  
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, bm.Width, bm.Height);
        bmpData = bm.LockBits(rect, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, bm.PixelFormat);
        stride = bmpData.Stride;

        // Get the address of the first line.
        IntPtr ptr = bmpData.Scan0;

        // Declare an array to hold the bytes of the bitmap. 
        byteCount = Math.Abs(bmpData.Stride) * bm.Height;
        bytes = new byte[byteCount];

        // Copy the RGB values into the array.
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(ptr, bytes, 0, byteCount);
    }
```

And this  how I unlock the bits.

```
    private void SaveBits()
    {
        // Update Stuff
        IntPtr ptr = bmpData.Scan0;

        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(bytes, 0, ptr, byteCount);
        bm.UnlockBits(bmpData);
    }
```

I implemented the IDisposable interface for this class. And I call the SaveBits there, so even if I forget to call SaveBits, the GC should do it for me.
And Yes, I do call bm.Dispose() and set everything to null in the Dispose method.

Comment: LoadBits and SaveBits are using different variables. one is `_bm` the other is `bm`, could you be doing unlock bits on the wrong object? Also could `LoadBits()` be called more than once before `SaveBits()` is called, that also would cause a memory leak. Try putting `bmpData = null` at the end of `SaveBits()` and put `if (bmpData != null) throw new InvalidOperationException();` at the start of `LoadBits()` and see if the exception gets thrown.

Comment: I refactored after I posted the question. So the "LoadBits" was showing the old var names. Allow me to update it.

Comment: If you do the null check and throw an exception, does it not throw?

Comment: I can't Load twice. The Bitmap class throws a exception, saying the memory is already locked.
Modifiyng the code per your sugestions and doing the null check causes a throw.

Comment: Well, if it causes a throw you found your problem, Something is writing to bmpData before calling calling `SaveBits` to clear it out. You are lossing the handle to the locked bits and that is the cause of your memory leek.

Comment: ._. I thought that was meant to test if I was locking / unlocking different objects. I added the following lines
LoadBits();
SaveBits();
LoadBits();
LoadBits();

It doesn't throw normally. That is, without calling loadbits() twice in a row.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62550/discussion-between-trauer-and-scott-chamberlain).

Answer (score 2):

You need to `UnlockBits()` when you're done.